# Proof that 2 groups are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra

Here is a proof that I am trying to solve:
Show  that  if $p$
and $q$
are  distinct  primes,  then  the  group
$\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_q$
is isomorphic to the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_{pq}$.

I have done a problem like this in the past but it was so long ago that I can't think of where to even start. Could someone give me at least a pointer on how I should do this?

Comment: $Z_{pq}$ has a generator of order $pq$ so you need to find an element of order $pq$ in $Z_p\times Z_q$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2540409/589

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  $(1,1)\in\Bbb Z_p×\Bbb Z_q$ has order $pq$.